# search with quotes and without quotes in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a string with double quotes. i.e. "this is text" when i search only this is text no results display. I want to search both string like with quote and without quotes. so what's the query made?

```
function template($val)
{

    $Qry11=Database::Read("SELECT subcategory.*,C_Name,description FROM subcategory JOIN category ON subcategory.C_id=category.C_id JOIN product_description ON subcategory.S_id = product_description.S_id WHERE S_Name LIKE '%$val%' OR C_Name LIKE '%$val%' group by subcategory.S_id");

    $List11 = Array();      
    $thisObjectName11 = get_class($this);
    while($arr = Database::Reader($Qry11))
    {   
        $data = new $thisObjectName11();                        

        $data->temp_Id = $arr[S_id];

        $data->C_Name = $arr[description];

        $data->Nm = $arr[C_Name];

        $data->S_Name = $arr[S_Name];

        $List11[] = $data;
    }
    return $List11;

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the query?

Comment: I add my code to que plz see.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the quotes like \" in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable in your query.

```
$var = '"this is text"';
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got that right use backslash to escape quotes:

```
 WHERE S_Name LIKE '%\"$val\"%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your condition is in single quoted like this...

```
WHERE S_Name LIKE '%$val%'
```

then if you want to search single quote (') like in $val.

```
$val = "some'some";
```

then replace single time single quote to double time (' to '') and search that will work proper.

```
WHERE S_Name LIKE '%some''some%'
```

otherwise in all search you can  directly search value like...

```
WHERE S_Name LIKE '%some"some%'
```

So in this you don't required any slashes in php...

Answer (score 0):

You can use json with some variable like 
 
 `$var = json_encode("this is text");` 
 and pass this variable to your query.